# Stripe ApplePay with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments, applepay

I am having some issues with getting ApplePay to work with angularjs.
I have managed to set up the normal stripe methods easily. But the ApplePay (which should be easy) is causing me some issues.

First of all, I have set up my sandbox account in itunes and logged into my IPad Pro and added the credit card as detailed here:

https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web

Then I navigated to my site and the apple pay button is not shown.
I have this method set up:

```
function applePayEnabled(callback) {
    Stripe.applePay.checkAvailability(callback);
};
```

which in my controller I use like this:

```
function checkForApplePay() {
    paymentsService.applePayEnabled(function (available) {
        console.log('is applePay available?', available)
        self.applePay = available;
    });
};
```

This method is invoked in my **init** method.
From what I can tell, this should be working.

Has anyone else had issues with apple pay on the web?
Does anyone know how I can fix the issue?

Comment: What is the console log outputting? In sandbox mode, it should always return true. Make sure you added your user account to the "Users and Role"

Comment: it outputs false :(

Comment: Can you try on an iPhone or Safari with handshake? Also, make sure you are serving your page over HTTPS. You can use ngrok for this.